# ImageCollection asset not found

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I have the script below to populate two Image Collections as part of a workflow to calculate Land Surface Temperature around solar parks.

When I run the script I get the error

```
Line 99: ImageCollection.load: ImageCollection asset 'Stateline_pre' not found.
```

(I have flagged this line with a comment in the code below - penultimate code block).

I have created an empty ImageCollection asset with this name, and have tried importing it into the script, too.  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
var Stateline_pre = ee.ImageCollection([ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20140110').set('MONTH','Pre_January').set('ORDER','04'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20140211').set('MONTH','Pre_February').set('ORDER','05'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20140315').set('MONTH','Pre_March').set('ORDER','06'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20140416').set('MONTH','Pre_April').set('ORDER','07'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20140502').set('MONTH','Pre_May').set('ORDER','08'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20140619').set('MONTH','Pre_June').set('ORDER','09'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20140721').set('MONTH','Pre_July').set('ORDER','10'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20140822').set('MONTH','Pre_August').set('ORDER','11'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20140923').set('MONTH','Pre_September').set('ORDER','12'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20131006').set('MONTH','Pre_October').set('ORDER','01'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20131022').set('MONTH','Pre_November').set('ORDER','02'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20131225').set('MONTH','Pre_December').set('ORDER','03')]);

var Stateline_post = ee.ImageCollection([ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20170118').set('MONTH','Post_January').set('ORDER','03'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_040035_20170226').set('MONTH','Post_February').set('ORDER','04'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20170307').set('MONTH','Post_March').set('ORDER','05'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20170408').set('MONTH','Post_April').set('ORDER','06'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20170526').set('MONTH','Post_May').set('ORDER','07'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20170611').set('MONTH','Post_June').set('ORDER','08'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20170713').set('MONTH','Post_July').set('ORDER','09'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20170814').set('MONTH','Post_August').set('ORDER','10'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20170915').set('MONTH','Post_September').set('ORDER','11'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_201710171').set('MONTH','Post_October').set('ORDER','12'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20161115').set('MONTH','Post_November').set('ORDER','01'),
                                    ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_039035_20161217').set('MONTH','Post_December').set('ORDER','02')]);

//Change vizParams depending on whether mapping L5 or L8 data
var vizParamsL8 = {bands:['B4','B3','B2'],min:0, max:20000,gamma:0.5};
var vizParamsL5 = {bands:['B3','B2','B1'],min:0,max:120};
var vizParams = vizParamsL8;

/////////////IMPORTANT//////////////////
///// Make sure you create the image collection in assets before trying to add images to it

///////////////CHANGE/////////////////
////Set site name for export to drive
var site = "Stateline";

////////////////CHANGE/////////////////
////Select collection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('Stateline_pre');
var collection = collection.sort('ORDER', true);

////////////////CHANGE/////////////////
////Set collection name for export
var collection_name = "Stateline_pre";

////Automatically select solar park coordinate
//var coordinate = Desert_point;
var coordinate = ee.FeatureCollection('users/prmonk/LST/Stateline_point');


////Set centre of map and zoom level
Map.centerObject(coordinate, 12);

////Convert collection to list to allow image export using loop
var list = collection.toList(collection.size());

//// Selects geometry solar park centre coordinate
//// Need to do this to allow buffer to be created
var solar_coordinate = coordinate.geometry();

//// Create polygon for area to export using buffer function
//// Change buffer area if needed
var extent = solar_coordinate.buffer(10000);
Map.addLayer(extent, {}, 'export_extent');

// Print scene_center_time for each image in collection list
for (var i=0; i<12; i++){
  var image = ee.Image(list.get(i));
  var time = image.get('SCENE_CENTER_TIME');
print(time);}

//// OPTIONAL: Loop to display images on map
//for (var i=0; i<1;i++){
//  var image = ee.Image(list.get(i));
//  var month = image.get('MONTH').getInfo();
  ///Use 'SPACECRAFT_ID' to automatically select correct visual parameters for image (i.e. L5 or L8)
//  var landsat = image.get('SPACECRAFT_ID');
//  if(ee.String(landsat).getInfo()==='LANDSAT_5'){
//    var vizParams = vizParamsL5;
//  }
//  else{
//    var vizParams = vizParamsL8;
//  }
//  Map.addLayer(image, vizParams, month,false);
//}

//// Export each image to image collection in Assets
for (var j=0; j<12;j++){
var image = ee.Image(list.get(j));
//// Use date to identify the image

// Line 99 (below) causes the error

var id = image.get('DATE_ACQUIRED').getInfo();
  Export.image.toAsset({
    image: image,
    description: id,
    assetId: "users/prmonk/LST/IC_pre/"+id,
   ///////assetId: "users/huntm/Solar_park_collections/Desert_post/"+id,
   scale: 30,
  region: extent  
  });
}

//// Export each image to google drive
for (var i=0; i<12;i++){
var image = ee.Image(list.get(i));
var image = image.select(['B1','B2','B3','B4']);
//// Use date to identify the image
  var id = image.get('DATE_ACQUIRED').getInfo();
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: collection_name+'Landsat_'+id,
    folder: site,
    scale: 30,
  region: extent  
  });
}

//print(collection);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a variable name as a collection ID.  This:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('Stateline_pre')
```

Should just be:

```
var collection = Stateline_pre
```

Comment: Thanks, Noel.  If I didn't declare that the next line threw an error.  The GEE documentation suggested it was because it didn't know what 'Stateline_pre' was, hence the declaration (though it didn't make any sense to me).  In the end, the way I got things to work was by removing the 'collection' variable and referring to Stateline_pre directly.  I'm still not sure why that made a difference, though, because as far as I understand things it shouldn't?